# anchor tag loses focus after page jump

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists, anchor

I've got bootstrap dropdown with different anchor tags < a > filling different < li > elements.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a onclick="item1()"> </a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a onclick="item2()"> </a></li>

</ul>
```

When I click element on list, a proper js function triggers and element on list changes background color (handled by bootstrap css, I think it uses a:focus for this). Everything is OK.

When I add a "href=#bottomOfPage" to every < a > element, then after clicking list element, there is no change in background color of this element. To be more specific, now I don't see which element on the list is chosen.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a onclick="item1()" href="#bottomOfPage"> </a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a onclick="item2()" href="#bottomOfPage"> </a></li>

</ul>
```

How to prevent page jumping (adding href="#Something") from disabling background color change ?

Comment: Are you add this `"href=#bottomOfPage"` to the `<li>` tag (what is invalid), or the `<a>` tag?

Comment: thanks for notice, of course <a> tag